# ERROR rbenv: 2.1.2 is not installed or not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, rbenv

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app project to my Digital Ocean vps using [this](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/deploy-rails-apps-with-capistrano) guide.

When it says:

```
cap production deploy:check
```

I get a error:

```
DEBUG [8906f2ab] Running /usr/bin/env [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ] on 178.62.204.53
DEBUG [8906f2ab] Command: [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ]
DEBUG [8906f2ab] Finished in 1.320 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ERROR rbenv: 2.1.2 is not installed or not found in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2
```

I ran:

```
rbenv install 2.1.2
```

Which resulted in:

```
Downloading ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/f22a6447811a81f3c808d1c2a5ce3b5f5f0955c68c9a749182feb425589e6635
Installing ruby-2.1.2...
Installed ruby-2.1.2 to /home/alucardu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2
```

When I check rbenv -v I get:

```
rbenv 0.4.0-129-g7e0e85b
```

When I check in my filescreen and go to `/home/alucardu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2` there's content there.

And when I check my Ruby I get:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
```

Could someone point me where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you run the `rbenv install 2.1.2` command? Locally or on the server?
Capistrano requires `ruby` to be installed on the server!

Also, `ruby` needs to be installed for the user you're deploying with.
It seems the tutorial you're following suggests to do the deployment with the `root` user (probably not the best practice), so in that case `capistrano` will look for ruby in root's home dir `/root/.rbenv...`

So the "fix" is:
- log in to the server as root user with `ssh root@<server_ip>`
- now, install ruby 2.1.2 as root with `rbenv install 2.1.2`

In case you don't want to mess with that, I created a [capistrano-rbnev-install](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-rbenv-install) plugin specifically for this purpose. The plugin ensures that you don't have to worry about ruby versions anymore.

Comment: After reading some blogs etc. I realized that I needed to install Ruby etc. on my VPS. Doing that now!