# Rails + Capistrano `rbenv: 2.3.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting an `rbenv: 2.3.1 is not installed or not found in $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1` when trying to deploy to Digital Ocean with Capistrano.

Does rbenv look on my local machine or on the DO droplet for the ruby version?? Or both for that matter...

The output on DO for `which ruby` is `/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby

The output on DO for `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

...so it looks like I have ruby installed correctly but it just isn't recognising it??

In my Capfile I have

`require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'`

I'm following the guide on [GoRails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04).

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684008/error-rbenv-2-1-2-is-not-installed-or-not-found) suggests that ruby should be installed on the root user. In my case I have installed it as user `deploy`.

Answer (score 6):

As per the post I linked to. I thought I was changing the path correctly to point to the deploy home directory but I was using `$HOME` instead of `/home`.

deploy.rb was updated to `set :rbenv_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv'` instead of `set :rbenv_path, '$HOME/deploy/.rbenv'` and it is now working correctly.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, capistrano throws `rbenv: ruby-3.0.2 is not installed or not found in /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/ruby-3.0.2 on 10.0.2.206` but on server 

I've installed ruby with `deploy` user and `which ruby` returns `/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby`.

My `deploy.rb` has `set :rbenv_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv`